# Unit Testing a view was dismissed in XCTestCase

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, xctest, xctestcase

I have an app using the `VIPER` pattern.

My `LoginViewController` is presented, some actions take place and the view is dismissed.

I'd like to assert that when `LoginPresenter` invokes `dismissViewController` within my `LoginRouter`, the view is dismissed.

I have a `UITest` that covers this behave however I have a code coverage issue within my CI Pipeline and a `UITest` is not enough to cut it.

I'd like to assert on the behaviour in code.

```
  import UIKit

final class LoginRouter {

    private var delegate: LoginRouterDelegate?
    private let view: UIViewController

    init(_ delegate: LoginRouterDelegate?, view: UIViewController) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.view = view
    }
}

extension LoginRouter: LoginRouterType {

    func dismissViewController() {
        view.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DismissalVerifier` from [ViewControllerPresentationSpy](https://github.com/jonreid/ViewControllerPresentationSpy). On the README description, scroll down to "How do I test dismissing a modal?"